# Get list of unread emails from Unix server

Tags: mailx

We are trying to get  a list of unread emails from our Unix server using `mailx -L`. However, the email subject gets truncated if its length is greater than 25 characters.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

`mailx` truncates its output to fit into the number of columns on stdout. To get the number of columns, it will try `ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, ...)` first - your terminal's window size - and if that fails, it will use the `COLUMNS` environment variable. So try this:

```
COLUMNS=999 mailx -L | cat
```

The `|cat` is there so that `mailx`'s stdout won't be a terminal, thus forcing the ioctl to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Mails usually are just text files (either in [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) or [Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) format), so you can process them with `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, or any scripting language. Common locations for mails are `/var/mail`, `/var/spool/mail` or some file/directory inside a users home directory.

To extract mail's subjects, you can use `grep` like this:

`grep -E '^Subject: ' /path/to/mail`

To remove the "Subject: " part, pipe it through `sed`:

... `| sed -e 's/^Subject: //'`

Filtering for unread message is more complicated, as the read/unread status is stored in a different mail header line. I guess you would need a slightly more complex script written in awk, Perl, Python etc. I have no tested solution ready for this.